# Backward compatiblility issues with StructureMap 2.6.1

Tags: c#, structuremap, backwards-compatibility

We have been using version 2.5.3 for a while and now we are trying to upgrade to 2.6.1 and have some compatibility issues.

1. The previous version had StoragePolicy-Classes such as `ThreadLocalStoragePolicy` and `HttpContextStoragePolicy` which all had a method to `DisposeAndClearAll`. The new versions seems to have the classes renamed to `X_StorageLifecycle` and the `HttpContext` has a method called `ReleaseAndDispose` and there's even a method `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects` on `ObjectFactory` which I presume does the same. BUT: Where has the same functionality for the `ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle` gone?!
2. We used to call `ObjectFactory.Inject("name", instance)` to add named instances for unit tests. It seems as there is no more overload for injecting a named instance?! I am using `ObjectFactory.Configure(o => o.For<T>().Use(instance).Named("name")` now but that doesn't feel like being the easiest way. What am I missing here?

Comment: Didn't know 2.6 was out.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that "someone" was just lazy ;-) as the functionality is still there but all the shortcuts are missing!

1. Call "new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle().EjectAll()" instead.
2. Call the same method on the ObjectFactory.Container object.